# Transfer value from a URL parameter to a asp:TextField

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I want to accomplish something like this

https://localhost/startsignatureppanel.aspx?StaffID=[value of the staff ID here]

Now here is my problem , I want to pass the value of staffID from this URL from this URL for instance

https://localhost/startsignatureppanel.aspx?StaffID=1002829

and have it show in the textbox. it does not put the code there

My code looks like this

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="startsignatureprocess.aspx.cs" Inherits="MYSignatureAccess.startsignatureprocess" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>

    <script runat="server">
        string mystaffID;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            mystaffID = "";
            if (IsPostBack)
            {
                mystaffID = Convert.ToString(Request.QueryString["StaffID"]);
                StaffID.Text = mystaffID;
            }
        }
    </script>            

    <body>

        <form id="form1" method="get" runat="server">
            <asp:TextBox ID="StaffID"  runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </form>

     </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change:

```
if (IsPostBack)
{
    mystaffID = Convert.ToString(Request.QueryString["StaffID"]);
            StaffID.Text = mystaffID;
}
```

To:

```
if (!IsPostBack) //You need is not postback, otherwise you never execute the if as your code is now.
{
    mystaffID = Convert.ToString(Request.QueryString["StaffID"]);
            StaffID.Text = mystaffID;
}
```

Hope tis helps.

Comment: You could just write: StaffID.Text  = Request.QueryString["StaffID"].ToString();

Comment: Thanks its fine now. Transfers the values corectly